# How to prevent ionic 3 app from freezing?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

My ionic 3 app's scroll on some pages gets stuck on latest ios version only and works again after minimize, I can not upgrade the app to ionic 4 as the app is huge and we don't have time. Is there a way to tackle this problem or a workaround to fix this in ionic 3? Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Here is my project's info

**Ionic:**

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)  
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2    
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
```

**Cordova:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms: android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.4    
Cordova Plugins: cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, 
cordova-plugin: ionic-webview : 1.2.1, (and 12 other plugins)
```

**System:**

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk)
NodeJS            : v8.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 6.4.1
OS                : macOS Mojave
Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, the issue was not related to the screen or scroll the issue was with the loader, the LoadingController was causing scroll to freeze. I replaced it with the native spinner dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this github [README](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#migrating-to-4x).

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed above issue after put below css in the app.scss and its worked for me

```
ion-app.platform-ios12 ion-content { pointer-events: auto; /fix scroll lock on ios12.2/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue using following css property

**-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**

This is momentum-based scrolling, where the content continues to scroll for a while after finishing the scroll gesture and removing your finger from the touchscreen

Comment: where should I apply this property? To ion-content ?? or is it somewhere else

Comment: In your container element class. Suppose scroll coming on  <div class='parent_div'>some code</div>  .parent_div {-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}